# Bundle Install Json Error

Tags: json, ruby, bundler

My ruby environment is pretty much setup. I can retrieve my Gherkins syntax via command line and run simple ruby web tests. But I need some other gems to complete the environment. All I need to do is get bundle install working, but can't figure out why it's not installing. I've updated my gems as well. I'm using Ruby 2.2.3 on Windows 10. Below is my output after trying to run.

```
C:\GitHubFiles\MyAccountWeb-Tests>bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/............
Resolving dependencies...
Using public_suffix 3.0.2
Using addressable 2.5.2
Using awesome_print 1.8.0
Installing json 2.1.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20180817-13500-1p562oy.rb extconf.rb                                                       creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean
                                                                                                                                       make "DESTDIR="

make failed, uncaught signal 11
Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-2.1.0 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.2.0/json-2.1.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing json (2.1.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '2.1.0' --source 'http://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.
                                                                                                                                       In Gemfile:
  appium_lib was resolved to 9.7.1, which depends on
    json
```

My source is already set to 'http://rubygems.org/'. I ran 'gem sources -r https://rubygems.org -a http://rubygems.org' to confirm this. My output after trying to run 'gem install json -v '2.1.0' is below.

```
C:\GitHubFiles\MyAccountWeb-Tests>gem install json -v '2.1.0'
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-2.1.0/ext/json/ext/generator
C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20180817-15312-13stnps.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-2.1.0/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-2.1.0/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="

make failed, uncaught signal 11

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-2.1.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.2.0/json-2.1.0/gem_make.out
```

gem_make text file

```
current directory: C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-2.1.0/ext/json/ext/generator
C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20180817-10044-ypvx4a.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-2.1.0/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-2.1.0/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="

make failed, uncaught signal 11
```

According to this link, I should try rake install. https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/json/2.1.0. But it just says rake aborted. No rake file found.

I also tried 'gem install bundler -v '= 1.5.1'' followed by 'bundle package', which created the same json error.

I've tried bundle update and bundle update json.

I read that there was a problem with json version 1.8.1 and ruby 2.2.3, so install json 1.8.3 version, so I tried gem install json -v1.8.3. Same json error.

I tried deleting my gemfile and running bundle update again, which replaced the gemfile and created the bundle install error again :(

I am stuck!

Comment: What is in `gem_make.out`?

Comment: I added the output for gem_make to the post

Comment: I think to build and install pure ruby version, you should clone the repo: https://github.com/flori/json and run `rake install_pure` inside of it, this is what it says. For development the difference in performance is not that important. But if you want to install it properly, you'll need to figure out what deps are missing. I suspect it's ruby headers, but it's hard to tell from the error you posted. There should be something else..